# Unity Firebase "Run resource generator" message repeating even though I have run it countless times

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

After updating Unity to *2018.4.15f1* and the Unity Firebase SDK to *6.9.0* (both happened at the same time) I have been getting a lot of log messages asking me to "Run resource generator". I don't think the tracebacks are too relevant here, so I'll just list the messages themselves:

- Run resource generator
- Run resource generator: "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Unity\My Project\Assets\Firebase\Editor\generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe" -i "Assets/GoogleService-Info.plist" -l --plist
- Run resource generator: run it
- Run resource generator: done
- Run resource generator: "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Unity\My Project\Assets\Firebase\Editor\generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe"
  -i "Assets/google-services.json" -l

I have executed these commands, they list the app package names for my Android and iOS releases of this app. I'm not sure what they are supposed to accomplish, they only seem to list the names. Both names are spelled identically. I have tried executing these commands in a prompt both with and without admin privileges. I have redownloaded both Google service files. I have also executed the python version of these commands, though they didn't even have any output. I don't know what I need to do to stop these messages from being logged endlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in Unity Firebase SDK 6.10.0